# Angularitics (GA) add fixed value to all tracked events

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, angulartics

I am using Angularitics (GA analytics) in my app.

Here's what I doing in my jade file.
a.btn(href="www.some.com" analytics-on="click" analytics-label={{UserID}} analytics-category="Some Category" analytics-event="Some Event")

Now I have a ton of these and the label is always UserId so i can track events by user.

Is there a simpler way to add a constant across the board value to all events. I have an angular app and want to add the userID for the logged in user to all events i track. Looking for a way to add that info without having to add it to each element i track in the html.

Answer (score 0):

I would just recommend you using GTM instead.

With Angulartics and GTM, you can access the dataLayer directly with

> window.dataLayer

So you can do something like this at the start of you controller or main app.

> window.dataLayer.push('userId','example123');

Then in GTM just read that into a variable and push into GA with the userId as label for the event.